# После изменений в файле scss браузер не перезагружается

Tags: javascript, gulp, browsersync

```
'use strict';

const gulp         = require('gulp');
const sass         = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const csso         = require('gulp-csso');
const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');


gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done){

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        },
        notify: false
    });

    browserSync.watch('./index.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);

    done();
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));

});


gulp.task('minify-css', function(){
    return gulp.src('./dist/css/*.css')
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});


gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('sass','minify-css', 'browser-sync', function(done) {
    gulp.watch('./scss/app.scss', gulp.series('sass'));

    done();
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таске browser-sync нужно добавить watch на изменения в файлах *.scss

```
browserSync.watch('./src/scss/*.scss').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

В такске watch указан неправильный путь к файлу app.scss

```
 gulp.watch('./src/scss/app.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
```